# Java Swing DefaultListModel containing storing more information

Tags: java, swing

I created a class to store two properties

```
public class MailEntry {
    private String mail;
    private MailFormat format; // this is an enum

    public MailEntry(String mail, MailFormat format) {
        this.mail = mail;
        this.format = format;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public MailFormat getFormat() {
        return format;
    }
}
```

the JList created for me by the Netbeans GUI is declared by

```
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
```

and initialized a `DefaultListModel`

```
private DefaultListModel<MailEntry> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
```

and set this as a model

```
jList1.setModel(listModel);
```

But what I get is

```
 error: incompatible types: DefaultListModel<MailEntry> cannot be converted to ListModel<String>
    jList1.setModel(listModel);
```

It seems that jList expects a model of Strings. But I'd like to store more item-specific information, which will be accessible through the GUI.

How can I work it around?

Comment: How is `jList1` one declared?

Comment: @marmistrz what is `jList`?

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing what `s` is here: `listModel.addElement(s);`. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `the JList created for me by the Netbeans GUI is declared by...` - well that is wrong as has already been suggested in my answer below.

Comment: oh, I didn't want to paste the whole code here since it's long due to the Netbeans generated stuff

Comment: @marmistrz, then fix the problem. You have already been given the answer. `I didn't want to paste the whole code` For future reference you were not asked to post the whole code. You were asked to post "minimal" code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @marmistrz There's not enough context to your question to give you anything more the guesses as to your problem. It would "seem" that the JList is declared as JList<String>, which means it will only accept models wch contain Strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you've decleared `jList1` as...

```
private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
```

but you're declaring the model as...

```
DefaultListModel<MailEntry> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
```

`MailEntry` and `String` are not compatible classes and the `JList` is expecting a `ListModel<String>` based model.

You need to change the `JList` declaration to support your model, something like

```
private javax.swing.JList<MailEntry> jList1;
```

Since you're using Netbean's form editor (don't get me started), you will need to select the `JList` from the "Navigator"

[image: Navigator]

Select the "Code" tab from the "Properties" tab...

[image: Properties]

and change the `Type Parameters` to meet your requirements

Answer (score 2):

```
private DefaultListModel<MailEntry> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
```

Should be:

```
private DefaultListModel<MailEntry> listModel = new DefaultListModel<MailEntry>();
```

And then when you create the JList you should be using:

```
JList<MailEntry> list = new Jlist<MailEntry>();
```

So everything should be consistent.

Note you should also need to create a custom renderer to display the data. The default renderer only uses the toString() value of the class. You can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and examples.

The other option is to just implement a `toString()` method in your class.

Comment: It doesn't have to be, in Java 7+ anyway https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond

Comment: Yep, I'm using the diamond syntax

Comment: @marmistrz, but you are NOT doing it correctly for the JList. The JList is a String, but the model is a MailEntry. The two do not match!!! Pay attention to the suggestion, not the comment.

Comment: If the JList is declared using <String> then changing the the deceleration of the model is pointless, you need to change the declaration of the JList to support the model

Comment: @marmistrz, why did you respond to the comment? The comment doesn't help solve your problem. Normally you respond to the answer. Typically by "accepting" the answer by clicking on the check mark if the problem is solved. If the problem is not solved then you need to provide additional information.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment distracted OP from your answer. I was simply trying to note that the diamond syntax is valid and does not directly cause the problem in the question. However, I absolutely agree that explicitly declaring the type in the instantiation helps to clarify the intent. I personally always do it, and it probably would help OP to do so as well.